# Multiline Message in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My Filestream source connector is reading a single XML file as multiple messages in kafka topic i.e each line in file as a separate message. How to get past this , i.e complete file to be read as 1 message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The FileStream connector cannot be configured to read multiple lines as a single message, and is also only meant to be used as an example for development purposes (according to docs), not part of a productionized ETL pipeline.

Therefore, you'll need some other way of reading your files into a single string. (But also note that Kafka has a default message size of 1MB, and is not intended for file transferring)

Comment: So is there a way you could suggest to take complete file as a single  message? Because consuming single message doesn't make sense at consumer  end.

Comment: I don't know what tools you have available, but any custom code would be able to read a whole file into a single string